# Specify compiler NVCC uses to compile host-code

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, cuda, nvcc

When running nvcc, it always uses the Visual C++ compiler (`cl.exe`). How can I make it use the GCC compiler?

Setting the `CC` environment-variable to `gcc` didn't fix it. I also couldn't find any option for this in the executeables help-output.

Comment: I don't think it is supported. If you want to use different MSVC version you can use `--ccbin`.

Comment: Oh really? I don't like the Visual C++ compiler.. >.> I thought it would be possible because NVCC uses GCC on Linux and Mac. Thanks.

Comment: isn't there '--compiler-bindir' option for nvcc ? you can also put this into nvcc.profile which should be located in cuda binaries dir

Comment: @NiklasR: It does. But IIRC it uses only MSVC on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, NVCC only supports the Visual C++ compiler (cl.exe) for host compilation.

You can of course compile .cpp (non-CUDA) code using GCC and link the objects with objects generated by nvcc.

Comment: What about Linux? Does it always use the default GCC version or is there a way to specify the host compiler/version?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44792397/749748